# How to use Cordova-plugin-purchase to do in-app purchase with ionic framework?

Tags: cordova, in-app-purchase, ionic-framework

I have been struggling with the implementation of in-app purchase for both iOS and Andriod in ionic. I came across tutorials regarding both the [cordova-plugin-purchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) and the [ng-storekit](https://github.com/AlexDisler/ng-storekit), but seems like the tutorials were based on the [version 3.4.1](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/tree/v3.4.1) of cordova-plugin-purchase, and the latest version now has undergone huge modification that the code is no longer applicable. I tried following the demo and API guide on Cordova-plugin-purchase, but no luck. Even `window.store` or `window.storekit` returns false.

Has anyone work with the latest version of Cordova-plugin-purchase in Ionic and successfully implement IAP? Any working examples demonstrating the initialisation and the purchase flow? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe this brand new plugin (iOS/Android supported) could help you:

https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

The author has written a recent post on his blog:

[Add In App Purchases To Your Ionic Cordova App - Step By Step Guide With An Example App](https://alexdisler.com/2016/02/29/in-app-purchases-ionic-cordova/)

and there is also a complete Ionic demo app on his Github repo:

https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-inapppurchases-app

Comment: awesome! Thank you! How did you found that?

Comment: Haven't used this plugin yet, been studying on In-App Purchases and found a few plugins and blog posts. Does this work and does it properly support both iOS/Android platforms? What about the Fovea plugin? I'm in desparate need of implementing in-app purchases for both platforms and we need to be store-ready very soon. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Beware: you should not use this plugin, the approach it takes might look simpler (thus better). It's because it doesn't handle all possible edge cases, like a purchase made on one device and finalized on another, or on a subsequent run of the application. People might pay for a product they'll never receive. Apple and Google have complex APIs for a reason.

Comment: as 2022, the plugin is "archived" on github and no more active...

Answer (score 1):

If you only need iOS support, Fovea's purchase plugin maintained backward compatibility with its legacy API. If neither window.store nor window.storekit is defined, then you probably didn't install it properly.

The new API is very well documented, supported and provides a demo app here if you wan't try it easily: https://github.com/Fovea/cordova-plugin-purchase-demo